# Iterating through list of strings returns individual characters

Tags: python-3.x, list, dictionary

I have a list of 3 letter strings that match the keys of a dictionary in my program.  I want to translate each 3 letter string using the dictionary, so I wrote a for loop.  Instead of translating each element in the list, it translates each single character in each 3 letter element, which accomplishes nothing because there is no pair in the dictionary.  I feel like I'm forgetting something basic about for loops and lists, but I can't figure out how to get this to iterate and translate how I want.  Code Below:

```
rnaCodonTable = {
# RNA codon table
# U
'UUU': 'F', 'UCU': 'S', 'UAU': 'Y', 'UGU': 'C',  # UxU
'UUC': 'F', 'UCC': 'S', 'UAC': 'Y', 'UGC': 'C',  # UxC
'UUA': 'L', 'UCA': 'S', 'UAA': 'STOP', 'UGA': 'STOP',  # UxA
'UUG': 'L', 'UCG': 'S', 'UAG': 'STOP', 'UGG': 'W',  # UxG
# C
'CUU': 'L', 'CCU': 'P', 'CAU': 'H', 'CGU': 'R',  # CxU
'CUC': 'L', 'CCC': 'P', 'CAC': 'H', 'CGC': 'R',  # CxC
'CUA': 'L', 'CCA': 'P', 'CAA': 'Q', 'CGA': 'R',  # CxA
'CUG': 'L', 'CCG': 'P', 'CAG': 'Q', 'CGG': 'R',  # CxG
# A
'AUU': 'I', 'ACU': 'T', 'AAU': 'N', 'AGU': 'S',  # AxU
'AUC': 'I', 'ACC': 'T', 'AAC': 'N', 'AGC': 'S',  # AxC
'AUA': 'I', 'ACA': 'T', 'AAA': 'K', 'AGA': 'R',  # AxA
'AUG': 'M', 'ACG': 'T', 'AAG': 'K', 'AGG': 'R',  # AxG
# G
'GUU': 'V', 'GCU': 'A', 'GAU': 'D', 'GGU': 'G',  # GxU
'GUC': 'V', 'GCC': 'A', 'GAC': 'D', 'GGC': 'G',  # GxC
'GUA': 'V', 'GCA': 'A', 'GAA': 'E', 'GGA': 'G',  # GxA
'GUG': 'V', 'GCG': 'A', 'GAG': 'E', 'GGG': 'G'   # GxG
}
self.aaList = []
self.codonList = ['AUG', 'AGG', 'CUG', 'AAG', 'AUA', 'AGG', 'ACA', 'GAC', 'GGC', 'GCC', 'GCC', 'CAG', 'CAA', 'CAG', 'CAG', 'GCG', 'GAC', 'UGG', 'CGG', 'GAC', 'UGC', 'UUC', 'AUC', 'CGC', 'GCC', 'GUC', 'GUC', 'GAG', 'AUG', 'CCG', 'GCG', 'GAC', 'UGG', 'GGC', 'AUG', 'GCG', 'AUA', 'AUC', 'AAG', 'GCC', 'AUG', 'CCC', 'CAG', 'GAG', 'AUG', 'GUA', 'AAC', 'GAG', 'CUG', 'UUA', 'CAA', 'AGC', 'CGA', 'AAC', 'GAC', 'CCC', 'UAC', 'UAC', 'AAA', 'UUC', 'GCG', 'CUU', 'CUG', 'CUA', 'CUG', 'CAG', 'AGG', 'GCA', 'CAG', 'AAA', 'UAA']
for codon in self.codonList[:]:
        self.aaList += codon.translate(self.rnaCodonTable)
    print (self.aaList)
```

I was expecting an output of ['M', 'R', 'L',...] translating each 3 letter string according to the dictionary, but instead I get:

```
['A', 'U', 'G', 'A', 'G', 'G', 'C', 'U', 'G', 'A', 'A', 'G', 'A', 'U', 'A', 'A', 'G', 'G', 'A', 'C', 'A', 'G', 'A', 'C', 'G', 'G', 'C', 'G', 'C', 'C', 'G', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'A', 'G', 'C', 'A', 'A', 'C', 'A', 'G', 'C', 'A', 'G', 'G', 'C', 'G', 'G', 'A', 'C', 'U', 'G', 'G', 'C', 'G', 'G', 'G', 'A', 'C', 'U', 'G', 'C', 'U', 'U', 'C', 'A', 'U', 'C', 'C', 'G', 'C', 'G', 'C', 'C', 'G', 'U', 'C', 'G', 'U', 'C', 'G', 'A', 'G', 'A', 'U', 'G', 'C', 'C', 'G', 'G', 'C', 'G', 'G', 'A', 'C', 'U', 'G', 'G', 'G', 'G', 'C', 'A', 'U', 'G', 'G', 'C', 'G', 'A', 'U', 'A', 'A', 'U', 'C', 'A', 'A', 'G', 'G', 'C', 'C', 'A', 'U', 'G', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'A', 'G', 'G', 'A', 'G', 'A', 'U', 'G', 'G', 'U', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'C', 'G', 'A', 'G', 'C', 'U', 'G', 'U', 'U', 'A', 'C', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'G', 'C', 'C', 'G', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'C', 'G', 'A', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'U', 'A', 'C', 'U', 'A', 'C', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'U', 'U', 'C', 'G', 'C', 'G', 'C', 'U', 'U', 'C', 'U', 'G', 'C', 'U', 'A', 'C', 'U', 'G', 'C', 'A', 'G', 'A', 'G', 'G', 'G', 'C', 'A', 'C', 'A', 'G', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'U', 'A', 'A']
```

How do I make the translation affect whole strings within a list, rather than each character of the strings?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I removed all the selfs for simplicity, you were close, your iteration was correct, but you need to iterate over each object in the list.

And then using that object to find the corresponding value in the dictionary you defined. Fixed your indentation with print which was incorrect.

Also you do not need to use translate, and I used append to add the values to the resulting list.

Hope that helps :)

```
rnaCodonTable = {
# RNA codon table
# U
'UUU': 'F', 'UCU': 'S', 'UAU': 'Y', 'UGU': 'C',  # UxU
'UUC': 'F', 'UCC': 'S', 'UAC': 'Y', 'UGC': 'C',  # UxC
'UUA': 'L', 'UCA': 'S', 'UAA': 'STOP', 'UGA': 'STOP',  # UxA
'UUG': 'L', 'UCG': 'S', 'UAG': 'STOP', 'UGG': 'W',  # UxG
# C
'CUU': 'L', 'CCU': 'P', 'CAU': 'H', 'CGU': 'R',  # CxU
'CUC': 'L', 'CCC': 'P', 'CAC': 'H', 'CGC': 'R',  # CxC
'CUA': 'L', 'CCA': 'P', 'CAA': 'Q', 'CGA': 'R',  # CxA
'CUG': 'L', 'CCG': 'P', 'CAG': 'Q', 'CGG': 'R',  # CxG
# A
'AUU': 'I', 'ACU': 'T', 'AAU': 'N', 'AGU': 'S',  # AxU
'AUC': 'I', 'ACC': 'T', 'AAC': 'N', 'AGC': 'S',  # AxC
'AUA': 'I', 'ACA': 'T', 'AAA': 'K', 'AGA': 'R',  # AxA
'AUG': 'M', 'ACG': 'T', 'AAG': 'K', 'AGG': 'R',  # AxG
# G
'GUU': 'V', 'GCU': 'A', 'GAU': 'D', 'GGU': 'G',  # GxU
'GUC': 'V', 'GCC': 'A', 'GAC': 'D', 'GGC': 'G',  # GxC
'GUA': 'V', 'GCA': 'A', 'GAA': 'E', 'GGA': 'G',  # GxA
'GUG': 'V', 'GCG': 'A', 'GAG': 'E', 'GGG': 'G'   # GxG
}

aaList = []
codonList = ['AUG', 'AGG', 'CUG', 'AAG', 'AUA', 'AGG', 'ACA', 'GAC', 'GGC', 'GCC', 'GCC', 'CAG', 'CAA', 'CAG', 'CAG', 'GCG', 'GAC', 'UGG', 'CGG', 'GAC', 'UGC', 'UUC', 'AUC', 'CGC', 'GCC', 'GUC', 'GUC', 'GAG', 'AUG', 'CCG', 'GCG', 'GAC', 'UGG', 'GGC', 'AUG', 'GCG', 'AUA', 'AUC', 'AAG', 'GCC', 'AUG', 'CCC', 'CAG', 'GAG', 'AUG', 'GUA', 'AAC', 'GAG', 'CUG', 'UUA', 'CAA', 'AGC', 'CGA', 'AAC', 'GAC', 'CCC', 'UAC', 'UAC', 'AAA', 'UUC', 'GCG', 'CUU', 'CUG', 'CUA', 'CUG', 'CAG', 'AGG', 'GCA', 'CAG', 'AAA', 'UAA']
for codon in codonList:
    aaList.append(rnaCodonTable[codon])
print (aaList)
```

Comment: This snippet is part of a larger program where there are multiple namespaces, but for the sake of this question I guess the self is not necessary.

Comment: Yea I assumed that would be the case, just removed them for this particular problem for simplicity :)

Comment: A list comprehension would probably be easier: `aaList = [rnaCodonTable[codon] for codon in codonList]`

Answer (score 0):

From docs on `string.translate`:

> Delete all characters from s that are in deletechars (if present), and then translate the characters using table, which must be a 256-character string giving the translation for each character value, indexed by its ordinal. If table is None, then only the character deletion step is performed.

...which is something completely different from what you're doing. This is what you should be doing:

```
aaList = ""
for codon in self.codonList:
    self.aaList += self.rnaCodonTable[codon]
```